# Creating a multiple data frame with sequential names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

How can I make the code below shorter?
I know this is a stupid way to code, but I am not sure how can I create the df0,df1,df2, ... dataframes and save them all as variables. Then merge them into one df.
For example:
mylist = ['ABC22', 'ABN33', 'ABM44', ..... 'ABF65']

```
df0 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[0]]
df1 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[1]]
df2 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[2]]
df3 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[3]]
df4 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[4]]
df5 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[5]]
df6 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[6]]
df7 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[7]]
df8 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[8]]
df9 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[9]]
df10 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[10]]
df11 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[11]]
df12 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[12]]
df13 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[13]]
df14 = data[data['ID'] == mylist[14]]
result0 = run_stage_one(df0, CurrentKeywordList)
result1 = run_stage_one(df1, CurrentKeywordList)
result2 = run_stage_one(df2, CurrentKeywordList)
result3 = run_stage_one(df3, CurrentKeywordList)
result4 = run_stage_one(df4, CurrentKeywordList)
result5 = run_stage_one(df5, CurrentKeywordList)
result6 = run_stage_one(df6, CurrentKeywordList)
result7 = run_stage_one(df7, CurrentKeywordList)
result8 = run_stage_one(df8, CurrentKeywordList)
result9 = run_stage_one(df9, CurrentKeywordList)
result10 = run_stage_one(df10, CurrentKeywordList)
result11 = run_stage_one(df11, CurrentKeywordList)
result12 = run_stage_one(df12, CurrentKeywordList)
result13 = run_stage_one(df13, CurrentKeywordList)
result14 = run_stage_one(df14, CurrentKeywordList)
Merged_df = pd.concat([result0, result1, result2, result3 , result4, result5, result6, result7,
                       result8, result9, result10, result11, result12, result13, result14], ignore_index=True)
Analysis = CategorizingOutput(Merged_df) here
```

Comment: Is `ApplicationID` at `[0]` while `ID` at other position intentional?

Comment: Why not just iterate over the values in mylist, within the loop subsetting your dataframe and saving that variable into another list, then using pd.concat at the end?

Comment: Could you simplify the example a bit to make it reproducible? Not sure about the contents of mylist, CurrentKeywordList, and CategorizingOutput are.

Comment: @QuangHoang No, I have updated the code, that was my bad

Comment: hi there, did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `ID` is an abbreviation for `ApplicationId` and all id's from data are in `mylist'.

```
result = [run_stage_one(dfi, CurrentKeywordList)
    for id, dfi in data.groupby('ApplicationId')]
```

Then merge and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I had to guess about certain parts of what you're trying to do, but I think something like this would work.

```python
data2 = data.loc[data['ID'].isin(mylist), :]
merged_df = pd.concat([
    run_stage_one(df, CurrentKeywordList)
    for ID, df in data2.groupby('ID')
])
Analysis = CategorizingOutput(Merged_df)
```

I'm ignoring that for df0 you used ApplicationID while for the rest it was just ID.